# Importing files into array with R

Tags: arrays, r, loops, import

I have multiple csv files that are within one folder.  Each csv file contains a table of 200 rows and 200 columns.  I can bring in each file individually and display it as an matrix.  I can also do a dir and list each file in the folder where they are located.  What I need to do is bring in each file, open them and then combine them into an array.  When I do this though I get a warning that there is no such file.

my code for this is

```
x <- dir(path=" ", pattern = ".csv")
num <- array(0,dim=c(200,200,length(x)))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  temp <- read.csv(x[i], skip=1)
  temp2 <- temp[,2]
  num[,i]<-temp2

}
```

This gives me the warning

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'test_1.csv': No such file or directory
```

Again, when I am working with individual files I can import them just fine and and list them and open them as a matrix.  Why am I getting this warning?  Why is R able to find my file when I do one at a time but not for multiple at a time?

Comment: please have a look at what is in your `x`, it does not look like it captured the files.   try `print(x)` and see if it has the list of expected files.  If not, please have a look at your `path=" "` argument

Comment: I didn't put anything here in the path, but in my actual code I have the path specified.  When I print x all the files are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First are you sure you are reading the list of files into the variable `x` properly. I think there are some issues with your for loop. Also are you sure you are in the same directory as those files? In the `dir` command you enter `" "` for the `path` variable, I am not sure what that means. Try this

```
> x <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
> num <- array(0,dim=c(200,200,length(x))) # in my case `length(x)` is 9.
> m <- matrix(rnorm(200*200),nrow=200,ncol=200) # generate some 200x200 matrix
> for(i in 1:length(x)){
    num[,,i] <- m # notice its num[,,i] and not num[,i]
}
> num[1:4,1:4,9]
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -1.5674073  0.05364477  0.8367233  1.7995047
[2,] -0.8613244  1.00400787 -0.2464169 -1.2897856
[3,] -0.7907845 -1.40617992  1.0596680 -0.5270983
[4,] -0.5206049  0.66253519  1.6820722  1.2017410
```